Symmetric matrix diagonalization on matrix of eigenvalues via congruence
I have a positive semi-definite symmetric matrix $M\in\mathbb{Q}^{n\times n}$ with Eigenvalues $\lambda_i\in \mathbb{Q}$, $i=1,...,n$ and at most one Eigenvalue equal to $0$.
Is there a way to bring $Q$ into its diagonal form $\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ by congruence transformation over $\mathbb{Q}$? Over $\mathbb{R}$ it is always possible but what about $\mathbb{Q}$? If all Eigenvalues are squares, then it should be possible but I do not manage to establish a proof. Intuitively, this should work, since one can first bring $M$ into its canonical form (assuming no zero EV) and then mutliplying by diagonal matrices from the left and the right containing the square roots of the Eigenvalues.
This question arises from the question when a positive semi-definite quadratic form is equivalent over $\mathbb{Q}$ to the quadratic form induced by the diagonal matrix of its EVs and, in particular, when do these two quadratic forms represent the same values.
Examples: where it worked (square case), from an exercise sheeted which I found online
$$\begin{pmatrix} 36& 24& 52\\ 24& 25& 55\\ 52& 55& 139\end{pmatrix}$$
Case where it did not work (with 0 zero EV).
$$\begin{pmatrix} 3& 0& -1& -1& -1\\ 0& 3& -1& -1& -1\\ -1& -1& 2& 0& 0\\ -1& -1& 0& 2& 0\\ -1& -1& 0& 0& 2\end{pmatrix}$$

maybe you should type in some matrices of interest in low dimension.

For some it works, for some it does not but maybe for the cases where it does not, I am doing my Gaussian elimination wrong. Or you mean add to the question?

yes, add to the question.....

Done. Hopefully that helps

Not sure what you are doing. The 3 by 3 matrix has characteristic polynomial $x^3 - 200 x^2 + 3074 x - 5816$ which is irreducible over the rationals.  That is, eigenvalues are irrational. Let me fiddle with the 5 by 5

I did not check whether the diagonal form given in the exercise with $\mathrm{diag}(36,9,9)$ contained actually the eigenvalues... in the end it is a diagonal form of the associated quadratic form but not the one with coefficients corresponding to the Eigenvalues of $M$. Thank you for the pointer.

From your description, I think you ought to be requiring  rational orthogonal matrices $P$ for the congruence $P^T MP = D$  diagonal.  This can be done two rows/columns per step, apparently called Givens Rotations, but rational. For Pythagorean $u^2 + v^2 = w^2,$  rows $i,j$  are $   \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{u}{w} & \frac{v}{w} \
\frac{-v}{w} & \frac{u}{w} \
\end{array}
\right) $   for positive determinant, a rotation, or negate the second row for a reflection with negative determinant.

I think this is going to be all the two by two cases.  In particular, there is no penalty for demanding trace zero. One may always add a multiple of the identity matrix. For that matter, the whole thing may be multiplied by $-1$ We take integers $r,s$
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{cc} 
r^4 - 6 r^2 s^2 + s^4 & 4rs(r^2-s^2) \\ 
 4rs(r^2-s^2) & -r^4 + 6 r^2 s^2 - s^4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
Next we take a rational orthogonal matrix
$$ P = \left( 
\begin{array}{cc} 
\frac{r^2 - s^2}{r^2 + s^2} & \frac{-2rs}{r^2 + s^2} \\ 
  \frac{2rs}{r^2 + s^2}  & \frac{r^2 - s^2}{r^2 + s^2} \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
The outcome is
$$ D = P^T HP = \left( 
\begin{array}{cc} 
\left(r^2 + s^2 \right)^2 & 0 \\ 
  0  & - \left(r^2 + s^2 \right)^2\\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
Note that the determinant is not just minus one times a fourth power, the fourth root of the absolute value is the sum of two squares. Quite restrictive.
